# Is there a way to show inside a groupby sum the values that don't give 0 using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Bear with me because I'm a beginner in python.

I'm trying to identify the values that compose a sum that don't add up to a 0, inside some sum's I will have the ones identified as *"Need treatment"* as *"True"* and those will have specific lines that are the ones that sum up to 0, the output I would like is something like the column *"Doesnotmatch"*.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
from pandas import DataFrame
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

# excel without change #
temp = input("Insert the name of the file")
df = pd.read_excel(temp)

# sum of the dimensions excel  #
df["Sumofvalues"] = df["Value"].groupby(df["DimGrpby"]).transform("sum").apply(lambda x: '{:.3f}'.format(x))



# Check if the status is 0 and the sum should be equal to the value & compares the value with the sum #
df.loc[(df["Sumofvalues"] != 0.00) & (df["Status"] == 4.00), ["Needtreatment"]] = "True"
df.loc[(df["Sumofvalues"] != df["Cost"]) & (df["Status"] == 0.00), ["Needtreatment"]] = "True"
df.loc[(df["Sumofvalues"] == df["Cost"]) & (df["Status"] == 0.00), ["Needtreatment"]] = "False"
df.loc[(df["Sumofvalues"] == 0.00) & (df["Status"] == 4.00), ["Needtreatment"]] = "False"



# change in the file.xlsx
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
print("Excel produced please check")
```

Sample of data:

```
DimGrpby  Number  LinkNr  Dimscnd  Dimthrd  Value  Status  Cost
F584585  7158988  7001236  2000000012  A  -5.480  4.00  12.460
F584585  7158987  7001237  2000000011  A  -6.980  4.00  12.460
F584585  7159631  0        2000000123  A  0.000   4.00  12.460
F584585  7159632  0        2000000124  A  6.980   4.00  12.460
F584585  7001236  0        2000000001  A  5.480   4.00  12.460
F897584  7001237  0        2000000002  A  6.980   4.00  12.460
F897584  8796541  0        2000000124  A  5.480   4.00  12.460
F897584  8796542  0        2000000125  A  6.980   4.00  12.460
F897584  8812311  8796541  2000000136  A  -5.480  4.00  12.460
F897584  8812312  8796542  2000000137  A  -6.980  4.00  12.460
```

Desired output:

```
DimGrpby  Number  LinkNr  Dimscnd  Dimthrd  Value  Status  Cost  Needtreatment  Sumofvalues  Doesnotmatch
F584585  7158988  7001236  2000000012  A  -5.480  4.00  12.460  TRUE   6.98  0
F584585  7158987  7001237  2000000011  A  -6.980  4.00  12.460  TRUE   6.98  0
F584585  7159631  0        2000000123  A  0.000   4.00  12.460  TRUE   6.98  0
F584585  7159632  0        2000000124  A  6.980   4.00  12.460  TRUE   6.98  1
F584585  7001236  0        2000000001  A  5.480   4.00  12.460  TRUE   6.98  0
F897584  7001237  0        2000000002  A  6.980   4.00  12.460  TRUE   6.98  0
F897584  8796541  0        2000000124  A  5.480   4.00  12.460  FALSE  0.00  0
F897584  8796542  0        2000000125  A  6.980   4.00  12.460  FALSE  0.00  0
F897584  8812311  8796541  2000000136  A  -5.480  4.00  12.460  FALSE  0.00  0
F897584  8812312  8796542  2000000137  A  -6.980  4.00  12.460  FALSE  0.00  0
```

Comment: your code looks pretty solid, can you add in your input and expected output data? just 5 rows of each (use dummy data if you can't use the real stuff)

Comment: I've had the sample of data and expected output as a linked image, can you please check? thank you!!

Comment: a linked image is not a [mcve] please read the link

Comment: changed accordingly